# how to filter '(' in navision 2013

Tags: navision

I want to filter the data 'Type(A)' in navision 2013.
I receive following error message "The filter is not valid for the Type field". Did not expect a'('.
I am using setfilter in c/side code. How can I filter '(' in navision?
Thanks

Comment: Please show the actual code you're using for the filter.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the following syntax:

```
SETFILTER(Type,'%1','Type(A)');
```

The same applies to filtering in a Classic Client / Development Environment - query should be wrapped with apostrophes:

```
'Type(A)'
```

instead of

```
Type(A)
```